# Rails - Dynamic vs static application for an e-learning platform

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am about to start developing an e-learning platform where users will be able to watch educational videos for school curriculums and take quizes and so on. The part im not sure about is how exactly should i go about creating each course on the website. Should I create it as a static page where all the content is added manually through code for each course and each video, or should i make it as a CMS whereby each video for each course is uploaded through an upload form and then displayed (using paperclip for example)? Can someone explain to me which is the best approach and why? Baring in mind that video uploading will not be on the user's part, only I will be uploading and adding content to the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go the CMS way, because it will make your life easier. By generating a lot of static pages, you will see that there are things you want to reuse at another point and then you have to code them another time. With a CMS you can predefine objects like a survey or video content, so that the admin or course leader can use these things in a more efficient way. Mostly, admins aren't techies, so they would be thankful for such a CMS.

This is also important for the following development. Let me give you an example:

You created hundrets of surveys, but then somebody discovers a bug. You need to change your code in too much places. While generating only one model of a survey means also only one fix.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I see your point regarding the CMS approach being more effecient in the long run.